# Directory.Delete(path,true) delete all the files and subdirectories but throw an exception

Tags: c#, file-io, io

I use Directory.Delete(path,true) method to delete a directory. Before deleting, I use this method to check if the folder could be deleted:

```
private bool FileCanDelete(string path)
    {
        try
        {
            //if this does not throw exception then the file is not use by another program
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(path))
            {
                if (fileStream == null)
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uaex)
        {
            throw uaex;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

If the return result is true, call the delete method. I can see all the files and subdirectories have already deleted, but the method throw an exception, "The process cannot access the file 'xxxxxxx'".

If the whole folder couldn't be deleted, I want the delete operation doesn't delete any file in the folder.

Comment: I see the function will return true even though you just instanced a `FileStream` of the file. Its a local variable and all, but I'm not sure if the garbage collector will have it freed just in time for the next operation (the delete call). Have you tried freeing it manually before returning true?

Comment: @Havenard I guess that it would not be a problem, since `using` ensures disposing of the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [.NET Transactional File Manager](http://transactionalfilemgr.codeplex.com/)

```
TxFileManager fileMgr = new TxFileManager();
using (TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope())
{

    fileMgr.DeleteDirectory(path);
    scope1.Complete();
}
```